# Why does using ReplaceAll twice produce a different result?

Tags: replacement

Why does this:

```
Solve[a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e == 0,  x] /.
    {2 c^3 - 9 b c d + 27 a d^2 + 27 b^2 e - 72 a c e -> F}
```

produce a different result from this?

```
Solve[a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e == 0,  x] /.
    {2 c^3 - 9 b c d + 27 a d^2 + 27 b^2 e - 72 a c e -> F} /.
    {2 c^3 - 9 b c d + 27 a d^2 + 27 b^2 e - 72 a c e -> F}
```

Comment: ... because the first replacement modifies the original expression? It's a bad idea to use replacement rules for algebraic manipulations. Replacement rules work at the language level, using the structure in `FullForm`. It does not care about any mathematical structure visible to you (except when it happens to coincide).

Comment: Then how should I go about this type of algebraic replacement operation in Mathematica?

Comment: It's usually problem dependent, but common approaches involve using `Solve`, `Eliminate`, `Reduce`, `GroebnerBasis`, etc. You might find some useful posts in [tag:algebraic-manipulations] (perhaps by Daniel Lichtblau or Artes).

Comment: You can also use `Simplify` with `TransformationFunctions -> {xf}`, where `xf` is defined by `xf[2 c^3 - 9 b c d + 27 a d^2 + 27 b^2 e - 72 a c e + rest___] := F + rest` and `xf[expr_] := expr`.  Look up the options to `Simplify`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the expression has parts of the form

```
pat + Sqrt[stuff + (pat)^2]
```

where `pat` is `Plus[2 c^3, -9 b c d,…]`.  That means the above has the form

```
Plus[2 c^3, -9 b c d,…, Sqrt[Plus[…, Power[Plus[2 c^3, -9 b c d,…], 2]]
```

*Mathematica* grabs the whole `Plus` but replaces only the terms that match `pat`.  What's important is that the rest of the whole `Plus` expression is not looked at further, so the part inside `Sqrt` is not replaced on the first `Replace`.

Minimal example:

```
a + b + Sqrt[(a + b)^2 + c] /. a + b -> F
(* Sqrt[(a + b)^2 + c] + F *)

% /. a + b -> F
(* F + Sqrt[c + F^2] *)
```

Since there's no limit to the depth `pat` may appear, `ReplaceRepeated` is a way to ensure that all possible matches are replaced.

```
a + b + Sqrt[(a + b)^2 + c] //. a + b -> F
(* F + Sqrt[c + F^2] *)
```

---

Another way I mentioned in a comment is to use `Simplify` with `TransformationFunctions`.  With `TransformationFunctions -> {xf}`, only the transformation `xf` will be tried and it's not too slow.

```
Clear[xf];
xf[2 c^3 - 9 b c d + 27 a d^2 + 27 b^2 e - 72 a c e + rest___] := F + rest;
xf[expr_] := expr;
Simplify[Solve[a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e == 0, x], TransformationFunctions -> {xf}]
(* output omitted *)
```

To include the regular simplification transformations, include `Automatic` in the list.  This took about 13 sec., since the expressions from `Solve` are fairly long.

```
Simplify[Solve[a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e == 0, x], 
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, xf}]
(* output omitted *)
```

Answer (score 0):

the result of `Solve[a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e == 0, x]` produces instances of parts with form `2 c^3 - 9 b c d + 27 a d^2 + 27 b^2 e - 72 a c e`. The first application of the replacement rule modifies them all to `F`. The resulting expression is then not returned 'as is' but is put in standard form. This is similar to the modification when you enter `(a + b) + (a + c)` and get as reply `2a + b + c`. Now this standard form happens to again produce `2 c^3 - 9 b c d + 27 a d^2 + 27 b^2 e - 72 a c e`, but only after the replacement rule has done its job.
So you need (want?) the `//.` (or `ReplaceRepeated`) operation in this case.
Even then, using a `Simplify` on the result could again generate parts that are replaceble by 'previous replacement rules'.