# How to replace multiple variables at once

Tags: replacement

I would like to make a replacement "c1 C1 -> F1, c2 C2-> F2...." such that the expression like this "c1 C1 c2 C2 c3 C3 c4 C4" becomes "F1 F2 F3 F4".

I used the standard replacement method: `c1 C1 c2 C2 c3 C3 c4 C4 /. {c1 C1 ->F1, c2 C2 -> F2, c3 C3-> F3, c4 C4-> F4}`. But mathematica only gives "F1 c2 C2 c3 C3 c4 C4", it only replace the first product.

What is the reason this replacement does not work? How could I make such a replacement at once?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: use `//.` instead of `/.`

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! 
In fact, I used /. for the multiple variables replacement before but never have problems. May I ask why this does not work this time?

Comment: Check out the help files for `ReplaceAll` and `ReplaceRepeated`

Comment: Some of the discussion [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38151/why-does-using-replaceall-twice-produce-a-different-result) is related.  There are probably other questions where issues related to matching subexpressions of `Plus` and `Times` are discussed.

Answer (score 6):

When it's not more complicated than your example, I do the replacement in the form

```
c1 C1 c2 C2 c3 C3 c4 C4 /. {C1 -> F1 / c1, C2 -> F2 / c2, C3 -> F3 / c3, C4 -> F4 / c4}
```

with simplified patterns that avoid tricky issues of pattern-matching.

The trouble is that the `FullForm` of  `c1 C1` is `Times[c1, C1]` which on the face of it doesn't exactly match the `FullForm` of `c1 C1 c2 C2 c3 C3 c4 C4`, which is

```
Times[c1, C1, c2, C2, c3, C3, c4, C4]
```

But the pattern-matcher does match them and replaces only a subsequence of the arguments of `Times`.  But since the `Times` expression has matched already, further rules are not applied.  We're lucky (as users) that it matches once, but unlucky that it doesn't match repeatedly.  That's why `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) works: it keeps applying the rules until there are no more matches.  First rule will be applied the first time but not on subsequent tries since it will no longer match; and second on the second try, etc.

Comment: Nice explanation and recommendations!

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a nice explanation!!